# Filter Images, Audio and video from Media in Views?

Tags: 7, media

I am using media selector module. I have a field collection item in my content type called media. I added a image field in field collection item. I created a view to display the images of a content. I uploaded 2 images and 1 youtube video. I dont want to show video in view result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider to use `File: Mime type` filter instead of `File: Path`.

For all video files the `Mime type` always has a pattern: `video/[video source or format]`

it might be for example:

```
video/youtube 
video/vimeo
video/quicktime
video/mpeg
video/mp4
```

Applying the filter `File: Mime type` contains `video` will solve the problem for all video files, not only youtube.